# Order of namespace in asmx web services

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

We have a asmx web service that are used by hundreds of customers. We recently did some refactoring including an upgrade to .NET 4.0.

We tested the refactored version by doing a lot of request using data from our logs as parameters and compared the raw result of the old and refactored web service. The only difference we found was that the namespace of the result was in another order. Note that old and refactored web service were on different servers. Different order of the namespace seems safe to release so that was what we did...

Today I was contacted by a customer telling me that they were unable to read our result and pointing this namespace issue as the reason. This seems very strange to me since they must have a more or less corrupt XML parser to get an issue like this. I would however try to isolate this, since we loose a lot of money every hour.

I reverted our project back to .NET 3.5 but get the same namespace order. But there seems to be a difference of the namespace order between the servers.

Does anyone know why the order is different? Does it have to do with .NET version, version of other components or is it just random?

From server one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://mydomain.com/">
...
```

From server two:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://mydomain.com/">
...
```

I'm a bit stuck...

Comment: You might want to confirm the order of the namespace is *really* the reason why the customer is unable to read the XML.

Comment: Cheers to someone who parses your xml on his own and thus the order of namespaces is meaningful for them.

Comment: Mike: They will not confirm this over the weekend and I'm in a bit of a hurry to solve this since we are the one loosing money. My boss is bugging me. :)

Comment: Your boss might want to take this opportunity to choose his customers better. Order of attributes is not significant in XML, _especially_ not order of namespaces.

Comment: @OlleJohansson - Was this ever solved?  Was curious..

Comment: @MikeChristensen No, not really. I tried to experiment with different frameworks and server combinations. But I diffident end up with a solid explanation. The solution was to close the customer down until they have fixed their implementation.